# Windows machine trying to path into another machine using the network folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-registry, network-shares, regedit

Does anyone know what the registry change is to c$ into a system from the file explorer ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You just use the file explorer given that you have permissions to do this. You don't use the registry. Unless you're asking something else, in which case you should edit your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Direct C$ access has been deprecated and highly discouraged.

The easiest way by far to do this, is to share a folder (high level) on the target machine and then map that folder.  This should provide all you need.

If you need to (and have all the permissions), you can share C: in Properties / Sharing, give it a name (say DriveC) and share that . This works as well.

Such a drive map can be put in a Batch File.